# How to choose a CSS file based on a session value in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm a bit new to ASP.net MVC 3.  I have to CSS files: "red.css" and "blue.css".  I would like to code my web application so that whenever `Session["color"]=="red"`, the browser will use red.css and whenever `Session["color"]=="blue"`, the browser will use blue.css.

What is the best practice for accomplishing this in ASP.net MVC 3?

I am using the Razor view engine.

Comment: I imagine that I could refer to `Session` in the View, but I believe that I am supposed to use `ViewBag`.  However, I would imagine that would require me to set the value on every ViewResult in the entire application.

Answer (score 0):

In your layout view you could try to do a conditional output

```
  @if (Session["color"].ToString() == "red")
    {
    <link href='@Url.Content("~/css/red.css")' rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    }
    else 
    {

    <link href='@Url.Content("~/css/blue.css")' rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    }
```

You'll need to set the session value at some point before the view is called or you will get a null error for accessing ToString().

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly on the Razor View:

```
@if(Session["color"] != null && Session["color"].ToString() == "blue")
{
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/blue.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}else{
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/red.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be as presentation problem to me so you should do it in a view. For example in `_Layout.cshtml.` You can directly access the `Session` in the view so I believe that is not a bad practice. Even if you transfer the value from the `Session` to the `ViewBag` in the controller you have the same `if-if` combination in the view, so it seems the same to me.

```
@{
   if( (Session["color"] != null) && (Session["color"] == "red"))
   {
       @: <link href='@Url.Content("~/css/red.css")' rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   }
   else
   if( (Session["color"] != null) && (Session["color"] == "blue"))
   {
       @: <link href='@Url.Content("~/css/blue.css")' rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   }
   else {??}

 }
```

If you really really insist to transfer it to the `ViewBag` you can have a base controller for your project and override `ExecuteCore` of the `Controller` class:

```
public abstract class MyAppBaseController: Controller
{
    protected overrid void ExecuteCore()
    {
       ViewBag.CSSColor = Session["color"];
       base.ExecuteCore();
    }
}
```

And this will be executed before every action you call(if your controllers inherit from this one) and you won't have to deal with it in every action method.

But again, that is exactly the type of stuff you would want to deal with directly in a view so the first approach would be my choice.